# How to set custom TimeZone in Android

Tags: android, timezone

In my Application I am displaying some info to the users according to the user's `TimeZone`. 
I am allowing the users to select different cities in the world and to get the required info. By default I will get the TimeZone of the user from their Device using

```
                `TimeZone myTZ = TimeZone.getDefault();`
```

And once the user changes the TimeZone , I am saving it in preferences. No problem in storing and retrieving the values from the preferences.

When another `TimeZone` is selected I set that TimeZone as default TimeZone using

```
       `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("my_timezone"));`
```

when I print the `TimeZone` in the Log I am getting the `TimeZone` value as I set it. But when I use that `TimeZone` in my calculations I am getting previous `TimeZone` Value.

So I think the problem is the TimeZone is not changing , I want the user to set the selected TimeZone as their default TimeZone in their device. How shall I do this. What is the mistake I am doing?

Getting stuck in this for three days. Any suggestions to get out from this? Quick suggestion will helps me a lot. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation for `TimeZone.setDefault(...)` -

> Overrides the default time zone for the current process only.
>
> **Warning:** avoid using this method to use a custom time zone in your
>   process. This value may be cleared or overwritten at any time, which
>   can cause unexpected behavior. Instead, manually supply a custom time
>   zone as needed.

Apparently to change timezone through code you have to use AlarmManager. See the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Jte3RymSOmk%5B1-25%5D).

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setTimeZone(timezone);
```

It requires this permission to be set in the manifest

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Still same problem for me. timezone is not correct. The value changes somewhere.

Comment: I am accepting this answer for giving the idea that timezone that we set using setDefault() will change the timezone for the current process only...